# How to shrink a text output in python

Tags: python

Hi 
I have a program in python which upon running displays an output on a single page. But when I print the output to an A4 size page the output does not fit on to a page, and gets distorted. Is there a way I could shrink my output or adjust the font size of my output, and print it on to a single page?

Comment: How are you sending it to the printer?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the [formatter module](http://docs.python.org/library/formatter.html).  You could use the end_paragraph function to set the length of your line and you could use the push_font function to reduce the font size.